# TZ=UTC+03:00 vs TZ=UTC+3 difference for Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, timezone, timezone-offset

Can someone explain to me, why `TZ=UTC+03:00` gives timezone offset `-180`, and `TZ=UTC+3` — `180`?

```
$ TZ=UTC+03:00 node -e 'console.log((new Date).getTimezoneOffset())'
-180

$ TZ=UTC+3 node -e 'console.log((new Date).getTimezoneOffset())'
180
```

At first I thought it is some Nodejs parsing responsibility, tried to find anything in Nodejs documentation, but failed. I tried to search through Nodejs sources, but it didn't work either. Then I started to think, that this relates to Posix and described somewhere in C/C++ libraries documentation. Failed to find it either...

And looks like when setting TZ for `date` command both variants gives same timezone.

```
$ TZ=UTC+03:00 date +'%Z%z'
UTC-0300

$ TZ=UTC+3 date +'%Z%z'
UTC-0300
```

I'm not interested in *how should I set TZ correctly*. I'm curious, WHY this different results.

UPD: Looks like rabbit hole is deeper, than I thought:

```
$ TZ=UTC+01:00 node -e 'console.log((new Date).getTimezoneOffset())'
-180

$ TZ=UTC+02:00 node -e 'console.log((new Date).getTimezoneOffset())'
-180

$ TZ=UTC+10:00 node -e 'console.log((new Date).getTimezoneOffset())'
-180
```

Does Nodejs just ignore it? (my local timezone is Europe/Istanbul, hence offset -180)

Comment: Because if you log and compare them in milliseconds you will have different values. TZ=UTC+03:00 should be behind time than TZ=UTC+3.

Comment: Don't understand, `UTC+3` looks like incorrect timezone at all, there is no such timezone here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`TZ` environment variable](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tzset.3.html) supports two different formats:

- It can be a POSIX time zone string, such as:

  - `NZST-12:00:00NZDT-13:00:00,M10.1.0,M3.3.0`
  - `PST8PDT`
  - `CET-1`
- It can be an IANA time zone identifier, such as:

  - `America/Los_Angeles`
  - `Africa/Nairobi`
  - `Etc/GMT-3`

In the POSIX format, (and in the IANA identifiers of form `Etc/GMT*`) the offsets are inverse from the normal ISO 8601 convention.  That is, `Etc/GMT+3` (or `FOO3BAR`) is what is usually written as `-03:00` - that is, 3 hours *behind* GMT.

When you pass `TZ=UTC+3`, since `UTC+3` is not a valid IANA identifier, it is interpreted as a fixed offset time zone *labeled* "UTC" that is 3 hours behind the actual UTC.

In the case where the `TZ` string is neither a valid IANA identifier nor a valid POSIX string, Node will fallback to use your system's local time zone.

There *does* appear to be a bug with Node (or perhaps with ICU) in that `UTC+03:00` should also be interpreted as a POSIX string.  While not commonly used, it does meet the `[+|-]hh[:mm[:ss]]` format described in the `TZ` specification.  I've raised a bug for this here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/46246

Comment: So `UTC+03:00` should be interpreted the same as `UTC+3` — timezone of Greenland and Brazil? That is really confusing, because wikipedia page called this timezone like `UTC−03:00`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%E2%88%9203:00

Comment: Also, thank you for explaining and raising a node bug, I'll watch it :)

Comment: When the string `UTC+3` is interpreted as a POSIX time zone, the letters `UTC` are just the abbreviation that will be used for formatting. It's not actually UTC.  You might as well have put `FOO+3` or just `FOO3`.  You may have seen this as something like `CST6CDT`, which says that there's an abbreviation `CST` which is fixed offset of 6 hours behind UTC, which is called `CDT` and is 5 hours behind UTC when daylight saving time is in effect.  Without the second abbreviation, it's just a fixed offset zone year-round.  POSIX time zones are quite confusing and quite awful, IMHO.

Comment: More on POSIX time zones in the second-to-last section of [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Comment: And yes, the offset of POSIX time zones uses the inverse sign of the standard form we are all used to (which comes from ISO 8601).